# Should we award more reputation for editing answers?

Tags: discussion, edits, reputation

It seems like we are giving users an incentive to come up with their own answer to a question, instead of editing existing answers. If I answer a question, I will earn 10 points for every upvote, plus another 15 points if it is accepted. If I edit an existing answer, I will only get 2 points if the edit is accepted.

Suppose that I find an answer to a question. Overall, it is a good answer, but it has a typo, or maybe a small but important inaccuracy. The best thing to do for the community as a whole would be to fix the mistake. But instead, I am incentivized to come up with my own answer, even if it is very similar to the existing answer. Now, everyone who sees the question with both answers will have to do more reading and thinking to evaluate which answer is better. Most people will probably pay more attention to the old answer, which will probably have a higher score, simply because it will have had more time to accumulate upvotes.

I think it would be a good idea to increase the incentive for editing answers. Either award more than 2 points for editing, or maybe give the person who did the edit some points if the answer is upvoted or accepted.

Comment: As a low rep user, I could see a lot of folks putting bad edits out there hoping to get some extra rep. With it only being 2 extra rep, I don't edit if it's going to be trivial. Though I do edit when I see a good amount of room for improvement.

Comment: I'm all for rewarding great edits, but I don't see the scenario you present here. If you post an answer of your own instead of editing a *typo*, there are likely to be social consequences. Also editing a typo doesn't seem like something that should tap you into any reputation earned by the post.

Comment: You can earn reputation for editing below 2k, period. Write your own answer (referring to the original) if you're after rep actually.

Comment: What are all these downvotes for? Is my idea a bad idea, or is this question not appropriate for Meta?

Comment: Downvotes can be used on Meta to express disagreement with the idea, even if it is well presented (which this one certainly is). It is nothing to worry about. You will not lose reputation points because of downvotes here

Comment: @EliasZamaria _"What are all these downvotes for?"_ Disagreement most probably.

Comment: @Pekka웃, what social consequences are there likely to be? Is it unlikely that some people are willing to accept mild shaming, and annoyance to others, in exchange for the rep?

Comment: @Pekka웃, fair enough. I can deal with the downvotes. I just wanted to put out my idea and see what people think.

Comment: `Is it unlikely that some people are willing to accept mild shaming, and annoyance to others, in exchange for the rep?` Maybe - but is it a widespread phenomenon right now? I doubt it. If we give editors a rep share, it should be for editing *questions* imo

Comment: somewhat related: [How can I acknowledge, thank, or otherwise approve of an edit?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142142/165773)

Comment: I downvoted this question and since you seem genuinely curious I will explain. While you have tagged it as a discussion it reads like a feature-request. There is clear bias in the presentation and there is no open premise, it is one sided. As a result, I voted on the feature presented: "more reputation for editing answers", because I do not think that will be beneficial. This is slightly controversial because of the discussion tag, but tbh this is very similar to a feature request. If you want to start a discussion on editing answers, perhaps it would be better to allow more facets to examine.

Answer (score 11):

I think that the current system is good as it is. The problem with your suggestion is that there's no algorithm that could tell if an edit is superfluous, grammatical, harmful, etc.

Nobody reviews edits that 2k+ rep users make. For all the other edits, I don't think it's realistic to ask reviewers to make that sort of decision with all the problems we have with robo-reviewers already.

Just make a new answer and give attribution to the original if you feel that your contribution is substantial. That allows the community to give you what you deserve for your efforts.

If the contribution is not substantial, it's not a good idea to post it as a separate answer. People look down on this (and may down vote) and you could even get flagged for plagiarism. You also seem to be talking about fresh answers, in which case, you can just tell the author about the problem so that they can fix it. Some people rely on the community feedback to refine their answer, and it's a bit rude to preempt that process.

Your suggestion to directly get the rep bypasses the community moderated checks that you would have to go past if you were making your own answer.