# More reputations for question and answer edits

Tags: support, feature-request, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I think you'd agree that to keep the high-standard this site has, editors, are also a part who are significant contributors.

Editing is hard, usually for non-Native English speakers like me, though I do it. And, I have 27 approved and 4 rejected till now. Though I try to maintain the editing standard (I don't know why they're rejected).

But, the question is I get only 2 reputations for each edit, whereas each edit isn't easy, some were hard.

Like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19772974

**I've to change the statement to make the question look sophisticated instead of a newbie-like and *The asker posted the error log console in image*. I wrote it into text and improved the overall formatting.**

It took time, and 2 reputations might not be a big prize for it.

This question's title is duplicate like [Should we award more reputation for editing answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322866/should-we-award-more-reputation-for-editing-answers)

**But, the content isn't same, I'm saying to give more reps based on edit quantity.**

**[Edit]
It might be a problem to give the low-rep user more points**. Then, Stack Overflow can increase to 50+. Once, you've done 50 reps, the rep addition will go from +2 to +4 or more

Comment: After you have done 500 edits, you won't get any points. Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252754/7311767

Comment: ...You *do* realize that your edits will now be looked over *just* to make sure that they're reasonable, right?

Comment: ...and looking at most of your edits, I'm not sure if the dubious usage of formatting and code blocks when they're not warranted is really worthy of more reputation points.

Comment: If you're doing things for the "prize" of reputation then you're kind of doing it wrong. [I appreciate reputation as a "thank you"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/340180/660921), but I don't do things *for* the reputation, I do them because that's want I *want to do*. So if I edit a post I do so because I *want to*; I might get some reputation in return (on some sites where I'm <2k) which is a nice extra bonus, but that's not what I'm doing it for.

Comment: For me, it seems like your main goal is to get reputation, not to help others, or learn...

Comment: @K.P. yes, I wanna help, and I want to get help. But, not wasting my time for free. Please don't take it as an offense.

Comment: In the suggested edit you linked to, you used `code formatting` on random keywords, which isn't allowed (that's probably why it got rejected). Code formatting is only for actual code. See [Inline Code Spans should not be used for emphasis, right?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135112/349538) and [Should I use code blocks when mentioning framework names/technologies?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/360491/4284627)

Comment: @DonaldDuck , thanks for the comment. As you can see, I already have 2 answers and loads of comment. I understood where my problem was.

Comment: I think even this question should be edited;) I think besides trying to improve formatting and possible complications for non-native speakers, the main reason editors should get more reputations is because **they sometimes are the ones that make a question usable**, but don't want to create a new answer because it's still similar or the original answer already has many votes despite it's incompleteness. Also, they sometimes KEEP an answer usable when the original author doesn't update the question according to newest technology standards and changes.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Let me ask you this: is reputation all that you strive to achieve by editing posts? If yes, then what happens when you cross 2000 reputation? Are you going to stop editing questions and improving the quality of content on the site because there's nothing in it for you?

The +2 rep is a "thank you", not an incentive. Please edit content that genuinely needs improvement (this includes not nitpicking over formatting, unless there are severe formatting issues) with the goal of genuinely contributing positively. Reputation is not meant to be a carrot tied to a stick, but a reward for being a positive contributor to the community.

Comment: You are saying edits aren't **incentive**, that means you're discouraging me to do an edit?

Comment: @Toaster No, I'm saying _reputation_ should not be looked at as an incentive. By all means, please keep making edits as long as those edits are constructive and make sense.

Comment: In my previous question , I also did reply the answer-giver to give me a guide to do so. I want to make better edits. **And I need examples**. Assuming a new-comer will know the all rules in bad.

Comment: @Toaster Take a look at [this user's review history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1033581/cœur?tab=activity&sort=revisions). They've edited over 46 thousand posts to date, and I must say their edits are rather good.

Comment: My edit was rejected saying `This edit did not correct critical issues with the post - view the revision history to see what should have been changed.`

But, somewhere I saw in StackOverflow to `not post image codes` because it makes problem to answer-givers. So I did the edit.

Comment: @Toaster I can't speak for the people who rejected your edit, but expanding links to images is counter productive, because it encourages users to continue this same behaviour. Most of the time, users post images/links to images of things that should be posted as text in the question and nothing more (this includes code and associated tracebacks).

Comment: Yes and no. Perfecting a question, if through updating it's code's content or through improving and formatting to make the actual answer  jump to the reader's eye and more, should be considered more important than it is up until now. Also, it's no secret that the key to using and improving this site beyond the basics requires reputation. etc etc! And as someone already commented and just like it is with many things, seemingly little (but good) changes can somtimes take a while. Not even talking about the subjectivity wether a change is useful, since it may be much more useful from asking eyes.

Answer (score 2):

Reputation can be gained much more efficiently by answering questions. A single upvote is already worth +10, whereas getting your question accepted is worth +15. Answering and asking are the *main* focus in this site, and are worth a lot of reputation because good questions and answers make StackOverflow a high-quality site. I would recommend that you ask good questions and search questions with your favorite tags so you can later answer them.

From the Help page, [What is reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), we have this note:

> suggested edit is accepted: +2 (up to +1000 total per user)

Gaining reputation solely through suggested edits is not a very efficient way of earning reputation though there isn't a risk of losing reputation through downvotes. Even though edit suggestions are no longer possible after you reach 2k, you also have to keep in mind that even if you gain reputation only through suggested edits, you will never get enough to get to 2k.

Pending edit suggestions may take hours to get to a decisive result (Approve or Reject), and it requires two Approve votes to make your edit suggestion successful, and two Reject votes to scrap your edit suggestion. Making trivial edits simply to earn reputation is both inefficient and can risk rejection or even a ban. Also, you are only allowed to have up to five pending suggested votes, and rejected votes will risk you of getting an edit ban.

Comment: answer accepted +15, please edit it and fix

Comment: `Gaining reputation solely through suggested edits is not a very efficient way of earning reputation though there isn't a risk of losing reputation through downvotes`

days ago posted a question on meta, they didn't like it, went to my main profile , did a rainfall of downvotes to my all questions and answers. Thought, they were relevant, I deleted them.

Now, think, I don't wanna be banned from asking for being a noob in reputation, So, I want to earn 500reps by edit first, then ask.

Comment: For me, I usually temporarily delete downvoted answers, until I can "answer" the downvote by finding a new solution.

Comment: If I'm not enough knowledgeable to find a 100 solutions?
If my solution took much time to find? If my solution was the best among the other answers? 

Then, in disguise, I'll never answer. Obviously, I hate criticism.

Comment: I understand. There is an urge to "race" to become the first to answer and the first to be upvoted. However, answering famous protected answers may also be a potent source.

Comment: Haha, I have only 1 and 1/2 years of experience in this field. How would I do a famous answer? Even, I saw when I ask a question, if it's not liked by the critics, they downvote, _But, when they fail to answer_ (`which one I asked about the content values present in android system for sms creation - it was a big question`) they even don't look at my question. Upvote so far.

Comment: Even, one question about the drive API. I asked and even I answered it, it was perfect. It took much time to do the research and extract the guide. But, they went and downvote them all. **Because I did a bad question(I mean they dont like) in META**. Even it was over 8-9 days,  36 times it was seen, no upvotes to my effort but, they were unable to answer

Comment: META downvotes are much more common, and the audience is for experienced StackExchange users. Even I don't consider myself experienced: I am only active for the past one and a half month.

Comment: I'm not saying about meta-downvotes, I even don't care of them, but I'm saying clearly that they downvoted my main profile questions-answers. Because I asked something to do about bad reviewers in meta.

Comment: @Toaster Again, that is the [Meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269349/1233251). It did *not* happen because you asked a bad quality in Meta, but because you *asked in Meta about your contributions*. Under the Meta effect, your content is more likely to be scrutinized.

Comment: @Toaster (generally you can expect that the downvotes are genuine, they are not because the meta question is bad, but because the post themselves are bad. The meta effect just make your question/answer get more popularity. (otherwise we have a script to detect voting fraud))

Comment: @Toaster so... you want more rep per edit because you want that 500 to go faster? Thats surely how it looks now :/. Anyway, if you really are banned, edits will not help you get out of it (unless they are edits to your questions that result in upvotes, that is)

Comment: If I get banned, I wouldn't waste my time editing ques/ans after that anytime in my life.

Comment: @toaster you are saying you don't want to be banned. You are also saying you edit to get out of that. It would be more productive for you to edit your content, not others', if you want the ban to be lifted....

Comment: I'm not banned yet. I don't want to get banned, so when I'm getting in problems I'm better searching Google or visiting blogs than asking to stackoverflow for getting banned. Becuase , may your question be good or not, you are downvoted

Comment: Actually, you have a strong knowledge at your field. I'm new to programming, I can't see any mistakes doing error in this condition of mine. After, some time, when I'd be better knowledgable to ask and answer my own questions I'd better then ask for it.

Comment: I can see you work with Google cloud apis, as far as I know, Google doesn't discourage people to learn programming neither they say to be zero to hero programmer in one day. You are in the profession, you know it's hard for a non-computer-science student to make a kickstart. I came here for my passion towards android, when I'll be enough I'll be there to help others. **Because you are allowed to help others in stackoverflow but not allowed to get** specially applied for a newcomer

Comment: @toaster I am just telling you how the system is. Why do you go in and try to make it about the product I work with or anything else? You are worried about a ban. I explain how the ban works, to explain to you that your edits, even if they improve the site, do not help you with that situation. Period. As a newcomer, you need to understand the site to be able to use it properly, no? That is what I am doing here.

Comment: Can you give me a good description of aking a question breaking into some methods, that will make me answer and not any upvote. I'm so worried about getting downvotes, I can't even ask one.

Don't give me community links, they're typically useless, doesn't work , I can't make any sense with them

Comment: @Patrice help me please

Comment: @Toaster I'm not sure what you're talking about. (1) are you question-banned or answer banned? You say that you're not but you also say "I can't even ask one".

Comment: @user202729 I can't even ask one from my fear to get banned

Comment: @Toaster There are [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) for guide how to ask a good question.

Comment: I will have a look at it.

Comment: @Toaster you can also post your question on meta first to verify if it's on topic and get suggestion for improvements. Don't abuse that of course, and don't post half researched questions hoping meta will fix everything. I personally work on questions I ask for roughly a week.... I never ask question because that week of research, invariably, gets me the answer. But if you make a good and genuine effort and check with the meta crew if it's appropriate, you should have a good reception.